# SharePoint Online - Profile Properties Update API - Operation is not valid due to the current state of the object

Tags: sharepoint-online, user-profile-property, api

I'm trying to run the Bulk UPA Custom Profile Properties Update API for SharePoint Online on our SharePoint Online tenant.
This one:
http://dev.office.com/blogs/introducing-bulk-upa-custom-profile-properties-update-api

It fails every time with an untraceable error:

> An unhandled exception of type 'Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ServerException' occurred in Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Runtime.dll
>
> Additional information: Operation is not valid due to the current state of the object.

It seems OK until this line in Program.cs

```
// Returns a GUID, which can be used to see the status of the execution and end results
var workItemId = tenant.QueueImportProfileProperties(userIdType, userLookupKey, propertyMap, fileUrl);
```

It always returns a GUID of

```
00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000
```

The parameters all look to be set up OK.

Can anyone help please?

Andy.

Comment: Could it be that it just hasn't reached out tenant yet?

Answer (score 0):

As per Vesa's comment in this thread the API isn't available on all tenants yet - https://github.com/OfficeDev/PnP/issues/1400